# htaccess https in parent but http in subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, redirect

I've tried implementing a number of suggested solutions to this problem but can't get anything to work.

I am using 2 .htaccess files, one in my root directory which reads as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(webservice|api) - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L]
```

This redirects all traffic to the main website through https which I need.

However in a subdirectory I want to disable the reroute and force all requests that go to this directory through http. The .htaccess file in /webservice/rest/ reads:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /webservice/rest/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/webservice/rest/%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^testingPost/?$ testingPost.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/?(\?([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\=\?\&]))?$ otherfiledirect.php?method=$1&params=$2 [NC]
```

There are a few redirects taking place, but the 3rd and 4th line in the 2nd htaccess don't seem to be doing anything - can anyone see what I'm doing wrong and how to keep https on the main site but force http on any url below /webservice/rest/ ??

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with the ssl config file in the server. Allow Override needed to be set to All under the secure virtual host at port 443. After changing that, the following code in the root htaccess file allowed me to force https across the whole website except a specific folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/webservice     [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L]
```

So any request to http would go to https. However I still needed to explicitly change requests to https on my specified folder to redirect to http, so added the following code after the above:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /webservice      [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Bullet proof.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `/webservice/rest/.htaccess` and make sure to test in a new browser:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /webservice/rest/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^testingPost/?$ testingPost.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?(\?([\w-=?&]))?$ otherfiledirect.php?method=$1&params=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava - doesn't seem to be working though. Perhaps it is something to do with the flags - in the root htaccess I have L after RewriteRule ^(webservice|api) - can't seem to make anything work though - any other ideas?

Comment: For testing rename root .htaccess and what URL are you using to test?

Comment: I disabled root htaccess completely but sub htaccess still isn't redirecting to http.

Comment: ok that tells me that something else is wrong in your setup. I also asked `what URL are you using to test`

Comment: hmm... Ok - seems to only be that line that isn't being read. Weary of posting the url in public as it's not very secure - how can I PM?

Comment: you can just replace your actual domain with `example.com`

Comment: www.domain.com is the root

Comment: That I know but what is URI after `domain.com` not working for you?

Comment: oh right - so for example I can access:
http version of www.domain.com/webservice/rest/GetForum?apiKey....
but can't access:
https version of www.domain.com/webservice/rest/GetForum?apiKey....

Comment: There are a number of different functions that can be called after webservice/rest/ but the API does not accept an https url and sends a 404 error when one is passed

Comment: So it turned out to be problem with your SSL config

Comment: Yep - thanks for the help, probably would still be fiddling with various htaccess configurations